# Provide a uniformly random number chosen from $[0,1]$

Tags: soft-question, algorithms, uniform-distribution, sampling

This is a soft-question and a riddle.

I am just wondering, that the phrase "pick a random number uniformly from [0,1]" is used very often in education, but in reality it can not be achieved. I mean, you can provide any number, but justifying that it was sampled uniformly seems impossible to me. Is it?

Provide (preferably explicitly) a number $x$ uniformly chosen from $[0,1]$ and justify how it was sampled uniformly.

...or justify this can not be done.

Comment: $0.85231.{}{}{}{}{}$ Seriously, though, what do you mean “provide a random number.” Do you want an algorithm?

Comment: A real in [0,1] will be indescribable with probability 1, but 'probability 0' is different from 'doesn't occur'.

Comment: I am just wondering, that the phrase "pick a random number uniformly from [0,1]" is used very often in education, but in reality it can not be achieved. I mean, you can provide any number, but justifying that it was sampled uniformly seems impossible to me.

Comment: In any event, there is no algorithm that takes a finite amount of time. You can flip a coin infinitely often to get a uniform random variable. Sometimes it is worth thinking of real random variables, until you are comfortable with them, as a kind of limit of random variables which take a finite number of values.

Comment: The limiting process then is much like the limiting process in defining the Riemann integral.

Comment: I think this is actually a good question and shows good skeptical thought, even though the answer ("no, that phrase is meaningless") is relatively simple. Don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: Or to be precise: The question *in the title* is meaningless and a bit stupid. Probably hence the downvotes. But I understand the question body as exposing exactly that, whether the title question is any good, correctly suspecting it is not.

Comment: Related on stats: [How do you know something isn't random?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/519260/318377) Also, relevant [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/221/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase

> pick a random number uniformly from $[0,1]$

is just a way to describe the standard uniform
continuous random variable.
That is, one which has a probability distribution
which is known as [continuous uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution). It is
precisely defined.

Actually producing a random number is a completely different task. As someone wrote

> Anyone who attempts to generate random numbers by deterministic means is, of course, living in a state of sin.

Not only that, but using physical sources of
randomness using nondeterministic means is doomed
by the requirement to "prove" that it produces a
**uniform** random real number because, it would
require infinite precision which is not attainable
by measurements.

Long story short. Picking a random real number uniformly
is just a manner of speaking. No actual picking is done.